# SciChart IOS fixed grid line and tick labels

Tags: ios, swift, scichart

I am trying to make the  X direction grid line and tick labels fixed at mid of the visible range, whether the chart is zoomed or paned.

I had try to create custom TickProvider for my xAxis:

```
class CustomTickProvider: SCIDateTimeTickProvider {
    private var tickCount: Int

    init(tickCount: Int) {
        self.tickCount = tickCount
    }

    override func getMajorTicks(fromAxis axis: SCIAxisCoreProtocol!) -> SCIArrayController! {
        let visibleRange = axis.visibleRange
        let min = visibleRange?.min.doubleData
        let max = visibleRange?.max.doubleData

        let array: SCIArrayController = SCIArrayController.init(type: SCIDataType.double)
        let step = (max! - min!) / Double(self.tickCount - 1)
        var current = min!
        while current <= max! {
            array.append(SCIGeneric(current))
            current += step
        }
        return array
    }
} 

xAxis.tickProvider = CustomTickProvider.init(tickCount: 3)
```

When I set `xAxis.autoTicks = true`, the grid line and tick labels will be relocated,they can't stay at the same position either.
When I set `xAxis.autoTicks = false`, no grid line and tick labels will be
drawn.

How can I get the effect of fixed grid line and tick labels?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the cleanest way to do it, but it worked for me in a comparable situation:
Edit the MajorDelta/MinorDelta after the visibleRange changed.